# how to make 2 differenct object of GetxController in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter

```
void main()
{
  NumberController controller1;
  NumberController controller2;

  controller1=Get.put(NumberController());


  controller1.addNumber(10);
  controller1.addNumber(20);
  controller1.addNumber(30);

  print(controller1.getNumbers.toString());

  controller2=Get.put(NumberController());

  controller2.addNumber(1000);
  controller2.addNumber(2000);

  print('Now '+controller2.getNumbers.toString());

}
```

here i want 2 differenct object of class NumberController which is extended by GetxController named controller1 and controller2

but here it is targeting only one object..so how to make them different object

what i want is

controller1 should contain only 10,20 and 30
and controller2 shoudl contain only 1000 2000 but here its showing

10 20 30 1000 2000

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
void main()
{
  NumberController controller1;
  NumberController controller2;

  controller1=Get.put(NumberController(), tag : "one");


  controller1.addNumber(10);
  controller1.addNumber(20);
  controller1.addNumber(30);

  print(controller1.getNumbers.toString());

  controller2=Get.put(NumberController(), tag : "two");

  controller2.addNumber(1000);
  controller2.addNumber(2000);

  print('Now '+controller2.getNumbers.toString());

}
```

Comment: what is tag? and whats the special use?

Comment: Tag is an identifier for that controller so you can identify amongst multiple controllers easily by their names.

Comment: is my question bad? why someone has down voted....i am sure many dont know about this tag

Comment: your question is alright and also tag is an important thing when you want different identifiers for different onjects.